# Recognize 2nd HDD

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive

I wanted to insert a 2nd HDD in my laptop.

After physically inserting it, how can I get my Ubuntu 16.04 to recognize it?

I just use it as a storage place, I do NOT intend to boot from it.

Is there a way to show this under devices of ubuntu?

I already tried

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

But it only showed the current one.

Laptop: HP Envy 17 j181nr 
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the output of the command `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's a long output, but it still does not list the other HDD, it only lists the one where my Ubuntu is. Even when I check Disks, my other HDD is not listed.

Comment: I think you need to double check that all cables and connectors are plugged in properly.

Comment: How can I do that? I mean I will reinstall my HDD, but how can I properly test it?

Comment: I mean the 2nd HDD you've inserted, make sure it's all plugged in properly.

Comment: Yes I understood. I will check again, but how can I know that it is plugged in properly? For example, can I see it in my BIOS under bootable devices?

Comment: BIOS should show it as a drive, but often without either BIOS or UEFI boot loaders it will not show it as a bootable drive. Most BIOS/UEFI list all connected drives somewhere.